# What is a quick way (without calculator) to determine that $(2^9 + 1)^2 + 2^9 + 2$ is not prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I came across the following expression $(2^9 + 1)^2 + 2^9 + 2$, which is divisible by 7 and thus not prime. Without this information and a calculator, how could I easily determine that this number is not prime?

Here is a way I thought of how to determine whether 7 is a factor, but I don't really like this approach because if I got that expression above, I'm not going to know to check for 7 right away, and this approach also requires me to know modulo arithmetic, which I'm not too familiar with.

$$
(2^9 + 1)^2 = (513*513) \\
(513*513) \% 7 = (513 \% 7 * 513 \% 7) \% 7 = (2 * 2) \% 7 = 4 \\
(2^9 + 2) \% 7 = 3 \\
(3 + 4) \% 7 = 0
$$

Comment: Simpler is to note that $2^3\equiv 1 \pmod 7\implies 2^9\equiv 1 \pmod 7$.  Thus your number is $2^2+3\equiv 0 \pmod 7$.  As to what would lead you to check divisibility by $7$...well, your number is obviously odd so if you just check the primes in order you get to $7$ quickly.

Comment: @lulu Is $(A*B*C)\%D = ((A \% D) * (B \% D) * (C \% D)) \% D$? Wasn't sure if this held for products of more than 2 numbers modulo some number. Actually, yeah, it should hold since it holds for the case of product of 2. I could just define $A*B$ to be a single number and see that the formula holds and expand.

Comment: Since $(2^9 + 1)^2 + 2^9 + 2 = (2^9 + 1)^2 + (2^9 + 1) + 1 = \frac{(2^9+1)^3-1}{(2^9+1)-1}$, where the denominator is a power of $2$, it makes sense to look for odd prime factors of the numerator. The only cubes modulo $7$ are $1,0,-1$, and so $7$ is a natural choice to look at in this form (for those who have some experience with modular arithmetic).

Comment: Note that the expression is $x^2+x+1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Right, but does that help me in any other way besides employing modulo addition?

Comment: @anonuser01  Well, if $x\equiv a \pmod n, y\equiv b\pmod n, z\equiv c\pmod n$ then $xyz\equiv abc\pmod n$ if that's what you mean.  Some sources use the $a\%n$ notation to refer specifically to the remainder you get on dividing $a$ by $n$ and if that's what you meant, some care must be taken.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. When I googled modulo arithmetic earlier, I just saw it for the case of $xy \equiv ab$ (mod n). But I think the following general formula holds:

$$
\left( \prod_{i=1}^n  x_i \right) \% k = \left( \prod_{i=1}^n (x_i) \% k \right) \% k
$$

Comment: You may also try using $7, 139, 271, 973, 1897, 37669$

Answer (score 4):

The factors are $7\cdot 139\cdot 271$; it's not getting much better by avoiding $7$. One thing that does help is that $2^3\equiv 1\pmod 7$, so the expression looks like $(1+1)^2+1+2\pmod 7$, which is immediately zero.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to know to check for $7$.

Your number is clearly a polynomial in $2^9$, so the first thing I would think of is to see if this polynomial factors. Letting $n=2^9$, the polynomial is $n^2+3n+3$, so no luck there.

You may notice that this number is $\frac{(n+1)^3-1}{n}$, so we want to find a factor of $(2^9+1)^3-1$ that is odd. Because the only (easy) way to factor a cube minus one is the factorization $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, we might want to try some prime factors. We can tell that $3$ doesn't divide our number since $3\nmid n$. Also, you can check (or you might know) that $x^3\equiv 1\bmod p$ if and only if $x\equiv 1\bmod p$ for all primes $p$ that are $2\bmod 3$. This means we only want to worry about primes that are $1\bmod 3$, the smallest of which is $7$.

Answer (score 1):

this expression is equal to

$2^{18}+2^{10}+2^9+3=(7+1)^6+2{(7+1)^3}+(7+1)^3+3$

( by binomial theorem )

= $7m+1+2(7k+1)+7l+1+3$
=$7p+7$ which is a multiple of 7

Answer (score 1):

By Euler theorem $2^6≡1 \mod 7$ thus:
$$2^{18} + 2^{10} + 1 + 2^9 + 2≡1+2^4+1+2^3+2\mod 7$$
which reduces to
$$28≡0 \mod  7$$

Answer (score 0):

$$A=(2^9 + 1)^2 + 2^9 + 2$$

> $$\begin{align}\color{red}{A-7}=\left(2^9-1+2\right)^2+2^9+2-7=(a+2)^2+2^9-5=a^2+4a+2^9-1=a^2+4a+a=\color{red}{a^2+5a}\end{align}$$
>
> ,where $a=2^9-1=\left(2^3\right)^3-1=\left(2^3-1\right)\left(2^6+2^3+1\right)=7×\left(2^6+2^3+1\right).$

So, $(A-7) \mod 7=0 \Longrightarrow A\mod 7=0.$

**The shorter way can be done as follows:** (based on the result we get)

$$\begin{align} (2^9 + 1)^2 + 2^9 + 2= 49×\left(2^6+2^3+1\right)^2+35×\left(2^6+2^3+1\right)+7.\end{align}$$